# AJAX: How to display data on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

I have the following function below.  When a button is clicked, the function below is executed.  The function basically sends json data to the page "temp.php", via Ajax

I think the sending of data is successfull.  My main problem is printing/displaying the data sent by ajax to the "temp.php" page.

```
    **Orders.php:**

    function convertToJson()
    {
        var tableData = $('#productOrder').tableToJSON({
            ignoreColumns: [0]
        }); 
        var result = JSON.stringify(tableData)
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/app/temp.php",
            data: {result},

            type: "POST",
        })
          .done(function( json ) {
                document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML = result;
          })

          .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
            alert( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            alert( "Status: " + status );
            alert( xhr );
          })

          .always(function( xhr, status ) {
            alert( "The request is complete!", status );
          });           
    }

   **This is the content of "temp.php"**
   <?php
   $Id = json_decode($_POST['Id']);
   $Name = json_decode($_POST['Product Name']);
   $Unit = json_decode($_POST['Unit']);

   echo "<h1>$Id</h1>";
   ?>

   **This is the json data (var result) that is being sent by ajax**


   [{"Id":"43","Product Name":"Orchid","Unit":"Test","Rate(PHP)":"600.00","Quantity":"5.00","Sub-Total (PHP)":"3,000.00"}]
```

Comment: The error means that there is an issue with your server.

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem. The ajax request appears to work as expected in simulated conditions. The problem is most likely within temp.php as already noted in the error message.

Comment: Hi, I reworded the problem

Comment: What does `var result ` give you?

Comment: Hi @Handonam, this is the sample "result":  [{"Id":"43","Product Name":"Orchid","Unit":"Test","Rate (PHP)":"600.00","Quantity":"5.00","Sub-Total (PHP)":"3,000.00"}]

Comment: Doesn't `tableToJSON` convert the data to JSON? Why are you generating some JSON and then encoding the string of JSON in JSON? I can't see that have any effect beyond being confusing when you have to double decode it.

Comment: This is because if I only send "tabledata", javascript return [Object][Object]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the data you are sending:

> ```
> data: {result},
> ```

(which is shorthand for `data: {result: result},`)

So your form encoded data has one key in it, result.

Now look at the PHP:

> ```
> $_POST['Id']
> ```

There is no `Id`  in the data you are sending. Only `result`.

> ```
> $_POST['Product Name']
> ```

There is no `Product Name` in the data you are sending. Only `result`.

etc.

Comment: if this is the result data I am trying to send contains [{"Id":"41","Product Name":"Sunflower","Unit":"test","Rate (PHP)":"550.25","Quantity":"5.00","Sub-Total (PHP)":"2,751.25"}], how should I display the "result" variable in my ajax call?